# How to encapsulated sql field result with quotations

Tags: sql, sqlcmd

What command can be used to encapsulate the results outputted to a file with uotations as shown below :

```
"Name" "Surname"
"Joe" "Soap"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but you can add quotation to the result set by simply adding the escape sequence and you can export that to a file

```
select "\"Name\"", "\"Surname\""
```